# How to permanently delete a member of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Allow me to specify what I mean. Say I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

  vector <int> ints;
  ints.push_back(1);
  ints.push_back(2);
  ints.push_back(3);

  for(int i=0;i<ints.size();i++) {
   cout << ints[i] << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;

  ints.erase(ints.begin());

  for(int i=0;i<ints.size();i++) {
    cout << ints[i] << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

What can I do to make a version of this program that will start with `1`already deleted after the first time it's run? Essentially making `2` the beginning of the vector the second time it's run, and then `3`, before basically deleting every element of the vector after running it a certain amount of times. I'm a beginner programmer so sorry if this explanation wasn't clear.

Comment: Basically, the program running is in volatile memory, meaning, when the process terminates, all data is lost. The concept you are saying needs to be in a non-volatile memory, so you need to save it in some secondary storage e.g. hard disk.

Comment: @mr5: Write as an _answer_ please!!

Answer (score 2):

Use a file. You can load the contents of the vector from a file, print it out, erase the first element, and then write the contents of the vector back to the file. If opening the file for reading fails, you can assume this is the first time the program was run, and fill the vector up with the initial values.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> load(char const* filename)
{

    // try to open the file for reading
    std::ifstream fin(filename);

    // couldn't open the file, so generate initial content
    if (!fin) {
        return { 1, 2, 3 };
    }

    // read the contents of the file into a vector, then return it
    int x;
    std::vector<int> v;
    while (fin >> x)
        v.push_back(x);
    return v;
}

void save(char const* filename, std::vector<int> const& v)
{
    std::ofstream fout(filename);
    // put a '\n' between each number so that distinct numbers aren't
    // concatenated together. e.g. Three seperate numbers 1, 2 and 3
    // aren't combined to become a single number, 123
    for (auto x : v)
        fout << x << '\n';
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char const* filename = "something";
    auto v = load(filename);
    for (auto x : v)
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    if (!v.empty())
        v.erase(v.begin());
    save(filename, v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

- **Rewrite the code as you run it.** This is insane. Changing the binary of a compiled program is just not easy.
- **Store the vector in an external file.** You can do this with some basic parsing using `std::cin` and some deliminators; try this example, here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a4d7a1a3f525b7e

I can't really think of much more. But rewriting the program itself every time it runs isn't exactly normally allowed in C++--doing such a thing is more similar to the behavior of maybe viruses or Just-In-Time Compilers, both of which need to take liberties with the security of the system, and are probably not going to be worth it just to change the value of the starting number of a `std::vector<int>` every time the program runs.